# Is it true that $o(ab^{-1})=o(ba^{-1})$ for any $a,b\in G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to prove the statement written in the title.

My current work:

$o(ab^{-1}) = o(b^{-1}ab^{-1}b) = o (b^{-1}a)$

And I'm pretty stuck here. I can't find any kind of multiplication which can bring me from $o(ab^{-1})$ to $o(ba^{-1})$.

I also tried to find a contraindication in $S_3$ and I couldn't find anything.

Please give me an hint how to prove it or an hint why it isn't true.

Comment: Can you show that $o(g)=o(g^{-1})$ for every $g$ in $G$?

Comment: Oh the answer is yes. And in here I can see that $o(ab^{-1})^{-1} = o(ba^{-1})$. Is it correct? But I still don't get $o(b^{-1}a)$...

Comment: ?? You asked about $o(ab^{-1})$ and $o(ba^{-1})$, not about $o(ab^{-1})$ and $o(b^{-1}a)$. And no, the answer is not that $o(ab^{-1})^{-1}=o(ba^{-1})$, whatever $o(ab^{-1})^{-1}$ would mean.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry @Did , I was confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true since $ab^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}a$ are conjugate elements:

$$ b^{-1}(ab^{-1})b = b^{-1}a, $$
so:
$$ b^{-1}(ab^{-1})^k b = (b^{-1}(ab^{-1})b)^k = (b^{-1}a)^k.$$